# Android Q results in a series of "Unresolved reference:" errors for new classes

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-10.0

When compiling [this app](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Bubbles) in Android Studio Canary 10 I get a series of those errors. Presumably it is compiling against the wrong SDK, but it says android-Q in the gradle. Any tips?

Comment: Did you download the Q Beta 2 SDK? Bubbles are new to Beta 2.

Comment: Yes, I did. It definitely has to do with their being new, but I'm not sure why the Gradle is failing. There are no errors in the source editor.

Comment: Both Android Studio 3.3.2 and command-line builds worked for me. Is there anything unusual about your development environment? If you create a new project, can you reference those classes?